# What notation to use when accessing an adjacency list?

Tags: c, graph, traversal, adjacency-list

I'm attempting to do a DFS search on a certain graph, here I have attempted to write down the following code (I'm aware that there are many errors/warnings and mistakes I have made but this is only a start and I need some help).

```
int visited[];
static int last=-1;
int record_of_visit[];


void print_dfs(Graph* graph, int source_id) 
{
    //printf("not yet implemented: put code for part 1 here\n");
    visited[source_id]=1;                
    record_of_visit[++last]=source_id; 
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<20;i++) 
    {  
        if (graph[source_id][i]==1) 
        {
            if(visited[i] == 0)  
                print_dfs(graph,i); 
        }
    }     
}
```

The graph.c file implementing the adjacency list can be found [here.](https://pastebin.com/aJyef7da)

The graph.h file can be found [here.](https://pastebin.com/ifFM3sSf)

Here I am trying to access the graph which is an already built adjacency list, but the compiler would give me error when I run this program indicating that 
on `if (graph[source_id][i]==1)`

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

What am I doing wrong here? Also any tips or suggestions on what to improve in my still raw DFS implementation would be appreciated!

Comment: your paste on pastebin is private.

Comment: `Graph* graph` in your function declarations suggests `graph` only a pointer to `Graph`, not a pointer to pointer to `Graph`. Hence, derefencing it twice with `[source_id][i]` will not work.

Comment: You could at least include the definition of `Graph` somewhere in your question; external links are not a good idea (@yar's comment is just one reason why).

Comment: @Evert Sorry for the confusion I have made it public for access.. Just thought that posting that long chunk of codes would make people feel irritated...hence chose to add a link...

Comment: please add graph.h, too, I suppose there is the declaration of Graph

Comment: @yar Done. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Yeah I was struggling on finding an appropriate way to get the length of lists. For now I'm sticking with a finite number as the assumption. But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Np!

Comment: What do you want to access with `graph[source_id][i]`?

Comment: @yar I reckon it is wrong to do so, but I am trying to use the adjacency list (the one that graph points to) and loop through it, basically I do not know how to access it and loop it...

Answer (score 0):

You can access elements of a struct by a "dot", i.e. you can acces `n` from the first graph in your array by `graph[0].n`

Comment: Thing is the error I have indicates that the graph itself is not an array or something (hence I cannot de-reference it ), but it points to some lists/vertices, is there something like graph->vertices[a]->first_edge?

Comment: `struct graph ` is a structure, that contains three elements:  `n `,  `maxn ` and  `vertices`. You can acces the pointer of pointers  `vertices` with  `graph[i].vertices`. Then you can access an element e.g. by  `*(graph[i].vertices[0])`. Nevertheless, `graph` does not contain pointers to `graph`, so the recursion with `Graph*` will not work this way.